# Sympy function as Matrix

Tags: python, sympy

is there a easy way to define a sympy function with multiple outputs. I want to have something like this (currently I am construction it with a loop but it seems stupid):

```
f1 = Function('f1')(x)
f2 = Function('f2')(x)
...
fn = Function('fn')(x)

f = Matrix([f1,f2 ..., fn])
```

If there is an implementation to construct this I would be glad to hear.

Answer (score 2):

To do as you have done requires a loop somehow. Here is one way:

```
>>> f = [Function('f%i' % i)(x) for i in range(5)]; f
[f0(x), f1(x), f2(x), f3(x), f4(x)]
```

And here is another:

```
>>> f = [i(x) for i in symbols('f:5', cls=Function)]; f
[f0(x), f1(x), f2(x), f3(x), f4(x)]
```

(Wrap `f` with `Matrix` if you want...but what do you want to do with this list of functions?)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `FunctionMatrix`, which works just like `Function` but maps matrix coordinates to a matrix.

See its [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html#sympy.matrices.expressions.FunctionMatrix). Example from the docstring:

```py
>>> from sympy import Function
>>> f = Function('f')
>>> X = FunctionMatrix(3, 3, f)
>>> X.as_explicit()
Matrix([
[f(0, 0), f(0, 1), f(0, 2)],
[f(1, 0), f(1, 1), f(1, 2)],
[f(2, 0), f(2, 1), f(2, 2)]])
```

Comment: FunctionMatrix does not work just like Function

Comment: would be possible to make `f` (or the matrix) dependent on a further variable `t` such that the matrix can be differentiate wrt `t`?

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix with distinct functions as entries

```
>>> M = sp.Matrix(2, 3, lambda i, j: sp.Function(f'f_{i}{j}')(x))
[[f00() f01() f02()]
 [f10() f11() f12()]]
```